# Expansion of $f(x) = \frac 1x$

Tags: calculus

Is there any type of expansion for the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} $ that converges for all $ x \ge 2 $ ?

I understand why Taylor-related series won’t do the work, but I wonder if there is another way of expanding a function that would.

By the way, I’m not considering the trivial Laurent series $ l(x) = \frac 1x $

Comment: Here is some discussion:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51770/taylor-expansion-at-infinity

Comment: Even if $1/x$ is not in $L^2$ there is probably some way to make a series expansion as a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) using [Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions) as a basis.