# Taylor series at infinity

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm required to make a Taylor series expansion of a function $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ at $x = +\infty$. In order to do this I introduce new variable $z = \frac{1}{x}$, so that $x \to +\infty$ is the same as $z \to +0$. Thus I can expand $f(z)$ at $z = 0$: $$f(z) = z - \frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^5}{5}-...$$
Then I try to reverse the substitution but this is either incomplete or incorrect: $$f\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{3x^3} + \frac{1}{5x^5} - ...$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use the Taylor expansion of $\arctan(x)$ when $x \rightarrow 0$ and that
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*_+, \arctan(x) + \arctan\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and find the correct result.
But as @janosch points out, it's faster to use
$$
\arctan'\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)= -\frac{1}{x^2 +1}
$$
and fix the integrating constant to
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \arctan(1/x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and finally get
$$
\arctan(x) =_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{3x^3} - \frac{1}{5x^5} + o\bigg(\frac{1}{x^5}\bigg).
$$

Comment: Thanks, your explanation make sense! But could you kindly comment where this property comes from: arctan(x) + arctan(1/x) - pi/2 ??

Comment: You don't need to use that. You could start by calculating $\arctan'(1/x) = -1/(1+x^2)$ (by chain rule), then integrate, and fix the resulting integration constant by considering the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \arctan(1/x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @Stunt-man-mike Let $f(x) = \arctan(x) + \arctan(\frac{1}{x}) - \frac{\pi}{2}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*_+$. By differentiating, you find $f'(x) = 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*_+$. So $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*_+, f(x) = f(1)$.

Comment: @janosch You're right.

Answer (score -1):

Your expansion is not correct. You should find 
$$f(z) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{3x^2} - \frac{1}{5 x^5} + \mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^7\right),$$
which is a perfectly good expansion in the small parameter $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$. See also [Taylor expansion at infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51770/taylor-expansion-at-infinity).

Comment: Your expansion is wrong, it's $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{3x^3} -\frac{1}{5x^5} + \mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^7\right)$

Comment: @Monadologie you're right of course, my bad. I fixed it.