# Asymptotic expansion of a function

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

If you take this function:

$f(x) = \frac {e^{-x^2}}{1-erf(x)}$

and ask software like Wolfram Alpha to give you a Taylor expansion at infinity, it will output this:

$f(x) \approx \sqrt \pi x + \frac {\sqrt \pi} {2 x} - \frac {\sqrt \pi} {2 x^3} + \frac {5 \sqrt \pi} {4 x^5} + O((\frac 1 x)^6)$

This is very nice, and in some systems it works even better than the function itself when one wants to calculate $f(x)$ for $x > 5$.

However, I would like to understand how such result is obtained, or more precisely, how one could do it without recurring to CAS.

I looked up 'Taylor expansion at infinity', and found several posts and resources describing the $x = \frac 1 y$ substitution trick to be able to do an expansion at $0$.
In most cases, however, the functions being handled could be manipulated into the product of some rational term not defined at $0$ (e.g. $\frac 1 y$ itself) and a function $h(y)$ that was defined and differentiable at $0$, so one could expand $h(y)$, multiply it by the left-out factor and do the back-substitution $y = \frac 1 x$.
I would say this is not possible with my $f(x)$, is it?

$h(y) = \frac {e^{-{\frac 1 {y^2}}}}{1-erf(\frac 1 y )}$

Where do I go from here? What do I factor out?

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292694/taylor-series-at-infinity) it is suggested to differentiate the function (after the $x = \frac 1 y$ substitution), yielding an expression that can then be 'Taylored' to a polynomial and integrated to get the Taylor expansion of the original function.
But again, not only the expression one manipulates is rational, but also defined and differentiable at $0$...

This still does not work in my case, I think.

$h'(y) = \frac {2 e^{- \frac 1 {y^2}}} {y^3 (1-erf(\frac 1 y))} - \frac {2 e^{- \frac 2 {y^2}}} {\sqrt \pi y^2 (1-erf(\frac 1 y))^2}$

I really do not see how this expression takes me any further in solving the problem.

I also considered expanding separately the numerator and denominator of my $f(x)$.
It turns out that the numerator cannot be expanded at infinity (that's what Wolfram Alpha says), and for $erf(x)$, Wolfram Alpha yields this:

$erf(x) \approx e^{- x^2} (- \frac {1} {\sqrt \pi x} + \frac {1} {2 \sqrt \pi x^3} - \frac {3} {4 \sqrt \pi x^5} + O((\frac 1 x)^7) + 1$

Obviously I can see that if I use this expression, my $f(x)$ becomes:

$f(x) \approx \frac {e^{- x^2}} {1 - [e^{- x^2} (- \frac {1} {\sqrt \pi x} + \frac {1} {2 \sqrt \pi x^3} - \frac {3} {4 \sqrt \pi x^5} + O((\frac 1 x)^7) + 1]} = \frac {1} {\frac {1} {\sqrt \pi x} - \frac {1} {2 \sqrt \pi x^3} + \frac {3} {4 \sqrt \pi x^5} + O((\frac 1 x)^7}$

which is yet another expression yielding a pretty close approximation of my function for $x > 5$.

But again, I have no idea how that expression was obtained, or in fact why there is a $e^{- x^2}$ factor in it, as I assumed all Taylor expansions (or Laurent etc.) could only have powers of $x$.

**Could anybody please tell me where I am going wrong / point me to posts or resources explaining how to do this without recurring to CAS?**

Thanks!

Comment: What do you do with Stirling approximation ? You use the *asymptotics* which are series. Don't you agree ?

Comment: In general a common tool to obtain the asymptotic of various integral (such as the error function) is to use the *saddle point* approximation. This has different names in different context but there is a big literature on it.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{1-\text{erf}(x)}\implies \frac 1{f(x)}=e^{x^2} (1-\text{erf}(x))$$
The *asymptotics* of $\text{erf}(x)$ being
$$\text{erf}(x)=1+e^{-x^2} \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi } x}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi } x^3}-\frac{3}{4
   \sqrt{\pi } x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^7}\right)\right)$$
$$\frac 1{f(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi } x}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi } x^3}+\frac{3}{4 \sqrt{\pi }
   x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^7}\right)$$ Now, long division
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\pi } x+\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 x}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$

Comment: Hi Claude, we meet again :). I think you are assuming that I know what I am doing. I do not. That's why I am asking for advice. When you write 'the asymptotics of erf(x) being....' and then you plug there a formula that gives me the answer, well, *that* is exactly the part I do not understand how to do. Unless we are saying that some things in maths cannot be calculated or derived, but one just has to 'know them by heart'. I would hope this is not the case. So thanks again for your input, but again, I am trying to understand *how* this is done, not copy-paste formulae from CAS.

Comment: Just a supplement: the asymptotics (*if unknown*) of $$\frac1{f(x)}=\frac{2e^{x^2}}{\sqrt\pi}\int_x^\infty e^{-y^2}\,dy=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-z^2-2xz}\,dz$$ (as $x\to\infty$) is readily obtained using [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).

Comment: Thank you @metamorphy , I upvoted your comment because you explained where the formula came from. I see that you did $1-erf(x) = erfc(x)$, and expressed the latter by its integral definition. Then you took $e^{x^2}$ into the integral, I have no idea how. When I match the final formula to Watson's lemma, I find $\phi (z) = e^{-xz-z^2}, \lambda = 0$, which by application of the formula still does not give me the correct answer, so I am probably still doing something wrong, but OK, at least there is a concept of how this might be done. Thanks!

Comment: https://math.byu.edu/~bakker/Math521/Lectures/M521Lec28.pdf - so yes, I *was* doing something wrong, in particular skipping several changes of variables... :( which I did not even know I needed to do :( :(