# Taylor's expansion at Infinity and Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, taylor-expansion

Before I start, I apologize if I use wrong mathematical terms as I'm studying maths in French.
For example for us Taylor's Expansions are called [Limited Development](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9veloppement_limit%C3%A9), not to be confused with [Taylor's Theorem or Formula](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Taylor), as the former looks like [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/7ef9d2c1e1c1970a8b12c9fa4bff17d6e38d9922) and doesn't require **f** to be *n* times differentiable, unlike Taylor's formula which does and looks like [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/403b6736ae0329b8d98f136aafe15618d9da377d) (However, the latter if it exists equals the former, else, we can say the expansion exists).

Now, as the pictures showed, Taylor's expansion (Limited Development) consists of a polynomial of degree *n* or lower plus a little *o*.

In the case of an expansion at a real value of **x**, the formula pretty much covers it.
For values of **x** approaching infinity, this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51770/taylor-expansion-at-infinity) pretty much covered it well (**y= 1/x** becomes the variable for the polynomial so technically the powers are still positive (for **y**))

We also studied what we call Generalized Limited Developments (I'm not sure what they're called properly in english), but they are defined as shown in the following image:[GLD Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph7hk.png)

They are also defined at infinity (instead of near zero), the only difference is the multiplication of **x** to some power by **f** to get **g**, becomes division.

Now, my two main questions are:

- What are these 'Generalized Taylor Series' properly called in English? (A link to a course or wikipedia page is very much appreciated)
- In these expansion there are terms of **x** with positive powers and others with negative ones, so doesn't this mean that it's no longer a polynomial? and the original definition of a Taylor Expansion said it was a polynomial.

If you have any additional information about terminology, please tell me! Thanks.

Comment: It is a so long time I heard for last time the words *"développement limité"* ! By the way, where are you located ?

Comment: Algeria, we study in arabic all the way to highschool ,then college is suddenly french (supposed to change to english in the next few years)